# Script fails, but copy and paste from script works

Tags: bash, scripting

I made a script to check the computer's processor count
and then change all references of the processor number in another script
in accordance with that. 
I tested it first by copying and pasting it into the terminal. I can copy the entire script into the command line and it works. But when I run it as a script, it fails half way through.

Here is the script (I know it's clunky and there is definitely a simpler way of running it, but this was easy to write off the top of my head, if you have a better version of this script and a fix, then that would be awesome!)

```
#!/bin/sh
# This part works both in the script and when pasting into the terminal.
echo | nproc >  ~/tmp/ProcessorNumber.txt
echo | perl -pi -e 's/processors=1/processors=8/g' ~/Scripts/test.sh
echo | perl -pi -e 's/processors=2/processors=8/g' ~/Scripts/test.sh
echo | perl -pi -e 's/processors=3/processors=8/g' ~/Scripts/test.sh
echo | perl -pi -e 's/processors=4/processors=8/g' ~/Scripts/test.sh
echo | perl -pi -e 's/processors=5/processors=8/g' ~/Scripts/test.sh
echo | perl -pi -e 's/processors=6/processors=8/g' ~/Scripts/test.sh
echo | perl -pi -e 's/processors=7/processors=8/g' ~/Scripts/test.sh

# This part of the script isn't working when run as script
# but is working when pasted into the command line.
if (( $(head -n1 ~/tmp/ProcessorNumber.txt) == 1 ))
    then
        echo | perl -pi -e 's/processors=8/processors=1/g' ~/Scripts/test.sh
    else
        echo | ""
fi       

if (( $(head -n1 ~/tmp/ProcessorNumber.txt) == 2 ))
    then
        echo | perl -pi -e 's/processors=8/processors=2/g' ~/Scripts/test.sh
    else
        echo | ""
fi 

if (( $(head -n1 ~/tmp/ProcessorNumber.txt) == 3 ))
    then
        echo | perl -pi -e 's/processors=8/processors=3/g' ~/Scripts/test.sh
    else
        echo | ""
fi 

if (( $(head -n1 ~/tmp/ProcessorNumber.txt) == 4 ))
    then
        echo | perl -pi -e 's/processors=8/processors=4/g' ~/Scripts/test.sh
    else
        echo | ""
fi 

if (( $(head -n1 ~/tmp/ProcessorNumber.txt) == 5 ))
    then
        echo | perl -pi -e 's/processors=8/processors=5/g' ~/Scripts/test.sh
    else
        echo | ""
fi 

if (( $(head -n1 ~/tmp/ProcessorNumber.txt) == 6 ))
    then
        echo | perl -pi -e 's/processors=8/processors=6/g' ~/Scripts/test.sh
    else
        echo | ""
fi 

if (( $(head -n1 ~/tmp/ProcessorNumber.txt) == 7 ))
    then
        echo | perl -pi -e 's/processors=8/processors=7/g' ~/Scripts/test.sh
    else
        echo | ""
fi
```

Comment: Forgot to add, the aim of the script is to check the computers processor count and then change all references of the processor number in another script in accordance to that

Comment: TBH, I do not understand why did you do this so complicated? Is not it easier just use `$(nproc)` inside test.sh where appropriate?

Comment: It would, and i tried a few approaches with variables like this, but test.sh enters an environment that wont see the variables (but must remain in the environment for the script to work), the only way round it that i've found that works is to physically change the script using another script

Comment: What error do you get? My guess is that your `/bin/sh` doesn't support `if ((...))`

Comment: Why are you doing `echo |` all over the place? In particular, why are you doing `echo | ""`?

Comment: good idea but both  ((..)) and [...] seem to work. the reason i've been doing echo is i create a log file of everything thats then echoed on command line, i pipe after echo as it makes the commands work. i'm not skilled at this, very new to it and just trying to learn coding in my spare time, as it seems quite fun. I appreciate all the comments and help, its massively improved my understanding and coding (though I’ve got a long way to go before I’m even at a novice level of competence)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this script instead:

```
#!/bin/sh
sed -i -e "s/processors=[0-9]\+/processors=$(nproc)/g" ~/Scripts/test.sh
```

`sed` is a Stream EDitor. `-i` switch tells it to make all changes inplace, `-e` though optional, tells that the following argument is a `sed` script

Comment: I looked at sed and completely over looked the -i flag, and this single line is beautiful. Script is working great again, thank you. I've only been coding in the last couple of months with a spare hour or so in my evening, so my scripting is very clunky and poor at the moment, I'm trying to get more refined though.

Comment: You probably don't need the `\+` — it appears from the question that there is never more than one digit after `processors=` in `~/Scripts/test.sh`.

Comment: @G-Man tomorrow, the system could be updated to the hi-end server, what then?

Comment: @Serge: OK, good point, but (1) you're answering a question different from the one that was asked, and (2) the script that the OP already has (to the extent that it works) assumes a single-digit number of processors.

Comment: @G-Man OK, Ok, you are absolutely correct